# How to connect to redshift jdbc url using python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift

I have a database url that looks like this:

```
jdbc:redshift://<database_name>.company.com:5439/<database_name>?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

How do I connect to this jdbc url using python? What is a jdbc url anyway? Can I connect to this using:

```
import psycopg2
con=psycopg2.connect(
    dbname= 'jdbc:redshift://<database_name>.<company>.com:5439/<database_name>?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory',
    host='host',
    port= '5439',
    user= 'user',
    password= 'pwd'
)
```

Answer (score -2):

I am using a better way of connecting to Redshift via Python.
Please Follow the steps -

1. Create a IAM Policy for get credentials - [DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-iam-credentials-role-permissions.html)
2. Where to Attach this policy ? -

   a. Run the Python Code on EC2 or any other service -> Attach the IAM Policy to a role and attach it to that particular service or IAM Role.

   b. Local Machine -> Attach to the AWS User which you have configured on your local system (via aws configure CLI Command and by providing Access Key and Secret Access Key )
3. Lets Use a Config.ini ( as a central Place to store any static values ) -

My Redshift JDBC URL is like -

```
jdbc:redshift://dev.<some_value_like_company>.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev_database
```

My Config.ini File is like -

```
[Redshift]
port = 5439
username = dev_user
database_name = dev_database
cluster_id = dev
url = dev.<some_value_like_company>.<region>.redshift.amazonaws.com
region = us-west-2
```

Create a connection -

```
    #All Imports
    import logging
    import psycopg2
    import boto3
    import ConfigParser

    def db_connection():
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        parser.read('config.ini')
        RS_PORT = parser.get('Redshift','port')
        RS_USER = parser.get('Redshift','username')
        DATABASE = parser.get('Redshift','database_name')
        CLUSTER_ID = parser.get('Redshift','cluster_id')
        RS_HOST = parser.get('Redshift','url')
        REGION_NAME = parser.get('Redshift','region')
        client = boto3.client('redshift',region_name=REGION_NAME)

        cluster_creds = client.get_cluster_credentials(DbUser=RS_USER,
                                                   DbName=DATABASE,
                                                   ClusterIdentifier=CLUSTER_ID,
                                                   AutoCreate=False)

        try:
          conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host=RS_HOST,
            port=RS_PORT,
            user=cluster_creds['DbUser'],
            password=cluster_creds['DbPassword'],
            database=DATABASE
          )
          print "pass"
          print conn
          return conn
        except psycopg2.Error:
          logger.exception('Failed to open database connection.')
          print "Failed"

    db_connection()
```

4. Import and Call the function where-ever necessary.

I would prefer the above instead of hard-coding the values for UserName and Password for any user, because -

1. its simply not a good practice,
2. Besides if you use a public Repo (github), then it makes the username & password public which might be a nightmare if someone uses it for wrong reasons.
3. Using IAM is Free and Secured :p.

Do let me know if this helps, If you still need to connect to Redshift the way you wanted will post an answer later after trying it out myself.

Sample IAM Policy for Get_credentials -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "redshift:GetClusterCredentials",
                "redshift:CreateClusterUser",
                "redshift:JoinGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:<account_number>:dbname:dev/dev_database",
                "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:<account_number>:dbuser:dev/dev",
                "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:<account_number>:dbuser:dev/dev_read"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```